# Space and <br> codes in Cell Phones

Tags: php, mobile

I have bought a dedicated line and I'm getting the messages via PHP and API and email them to myself, here is the code:

```
$message = get_new_sms(); // A function I got from the API
mail('my_email@gmail.com', 'Test', $message);
```

But when I receive the email, all Space characters and `<br>` tags are dropped, imagine my text is:

```
'Hello Behz4d, how are you?'
```

What I actually receive by email is:

```
'HelloBehz4d,howareyou?'
```

**This also remove the next lines(\n)...**

After some Goggling, I found that the ASCII code for spaces and next lines is different in cell phones, so I should replace them, so I updated my code to:

```
$message = str_replace(chr(20)," ",$message);  // SPACE
$message = str_replace("%2B"," ",$message);  // SPACE
$message = str_replace(chr(226).chr(128).chr(169),"<br />",$message);  // Next Line (<br>)
$message = str_replace("†","<br />",$message);  // Next Line in iPad
```

But still, I get emails with dropped spaces and next lines...

Anybody had the same issue or any experience like this?

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for new line,

%0a

hope this will help...

Comment: this is not working, which cells this should work on? are you sure about this!?

Comment: I am not sure but i have used this for client with TWILLIO TEXT SMS API.